# SQLite extension binaries

Tags: json, sqlite

sqlite.org provides windows binaries for the core functions. Are there any pre-built DLLs for the various standard extensions - free text search, virtual tables and JSON in particular? I notice that the command shell as distributed does not support the table-valued JSON functions.

This seems a very obvious request, given the ready availability of binaries for SQLite in other respects, but I can't find anywhere online hosting pre-built extension libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line shell, as distributed, *does* support the table-valued JSON functions:

```
sqlite> select * from json_tree('["hello",["world"]]');
key         value                type        atom        id          parent      fullkey     path
----------  -------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
            ["hello",["world"]]  array                   0                       $           $
0           hello                text        hello       1           0           $[0]        $
1           ["world"]            array                   2           0           $[1]        $
0           world                text        world       3           2           $[1][0]     $[1]
```

Anyway, the SQLite library is meant to be embedded into your application, i.e., the `sqlite3.c` file (and any needed extensions not already included in the amalgamation) is to be directly compiled together with your other sources.

Comment: You are quite right, thank you. I was mistakenly using an earlier version of SQLite.

Comment: Though I would not agree with the implication of your "Anyway...".  A great strength of SQLite that has kept me using it for 10 years plus is the diversity of ways you can use it. For instance, testing some SQL in the command shell before embedding it, as in your own answer, and in my own requirement motivating the question.